# Как сделать проверку и вывод только уникальных чисел после генерации

Tags: php

Добрый день! Я только начинаю постигать php. Запутался сейчас с таким моментом: создал генератор числе с помощью функции `mt_rand`. Проблема в том, что не знаю, как сделать проверку уникальности сгенерированных чисел, отсеять повторяющиеся и сгенерировать по новой недостающее количество. Помогите пожалуйста решить задачу. Вот код:

```
<?php
$even = $_POST['even'];
$odd = $_POST['odd'];
$number = $_POST['pir'];
$start2 = $_POST['start2'];
$end2 = $_POST['end2'];
function clean($value = "") {
    $value = trim($value); //для удаления пробелов из начала и конца строки
    $value = stripslashes($value); //для удаления экранированных символов ("Ваc зовут O\'reilly?" => "Вас зовут O'reilly?")
    $value = strip_tags($value); //для удаления HTML и PHP тегов
    $value = htmlspecialchars($value); //преобразует специальные символы в HTML-сущности ('&' преобразуется в '&' и т.д.)

    return $value;
}
$number = clean($number);
$start2 = clean($start2);
$end2 = clean($end2);
for ($i=1; $i<=$number; $i++){
  if ($number>300) {
      echo '<span style="display:inline-block; margin-left:20px; margin-bottom:20px;">Максимальное количество сгенерированных чисел не может больше 100</span>';
  exit();
  }
  elseif ($end2 <= $start2) {
    echo '<span style="display:inline-block; margin-left:20px; margin-bottom:20px;">Введите второе число диапазона большее, чем первое.</span>';
    exit();
  }

$num1 = mt_rand($start2, $end2);

  if (isset($even) or isset($odd)) {
    if (isset($even)) {
      if ($num1 % 2 == 0) {
           echo '<span style="display:inline-block; margin-left:20px; margin-bottom:20px;">'.$num1.'</span>';    
      }
      else {
          $numeven = $num1 +1;    
          echo '<span style="display:inline-block; margin-left:20px; margin-bottom:20px;">'.$numeven.'</span>';    
      }    
    }
    elseif (isset($odd)) {
      if ($num1 % 2 !== 0) {
           echo '<span style="display:inline-block; margin-left:20px; margin-bottom:20px;">'.$num1.'</span>';
      }
      else {
          $numodd = $num1 - 1;    
          echo '<span style="display:inline-block; margin-left:20px; margin-bottom:20px;">'.$numodd.'</span>';
      }    
    }  
  }
      else {
          echo '<span style="display:inline-block; margin-left:20px; margin-bottom:20px;">'.$num1.'</span>';
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Вариант для малых диапазонов $min-$max.

```
$target = array_slice(shuffle(range($min, $max)),0,$num);
```

Вариант для больших диапазонов $min-$max

```
$tmp = array();
while(count($tmp)<$num)$tmp[mt_rand($min,$max)]=true;
$target = array_keys($tmp);
```

Comment: Мда, изливаюсь тут, укорачиваю код, а какой-то Pro написал его в 3 строчки. Плюсю

Comment: память сильно хавается. при `min=0` и `max=2^20` скушал примерно **60мб**

Comment: @Артём, что логично. Нет универсального, хорошего метода. Под каждую задачу свой инструмент.